# How to migrate single datacenter cluster to multiple datacenter cluster in cassandra>

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Provide recommended configuration to migrate the data from the single data center cassandra cluster to multiple data center cassandra cluster. Currenlty i have the single data center cluster environment with following configurations,
i) No of nodes: 3
ii) Replication Factor : 2
iii) Strategy: SimpleStrategy
iv) endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch

And now i am planning to add 2 more nodes which is in different location. So i thought of moving to Multiple data center cluster with following confiruations.
i) No of nodes: 5
ii) RF: dc1=2, dc2=2
iii) Strategy: NetworkTopolofyStrategy
iv). endpoint_snitch: PropertyFileSnitch (I have the cassandra.topolofy.properties file)

What is the procedure to migrate the data without losing any data?

Please let me know the recommended steps to follow or any guide which i can refer. Please let me know if further info is required.

Answer (score 2):

1. Complete repairs on all nodes.
2. Take snapshot on all nodes to have a fall back point.
3. Decommission each node that is not a pure Cassandra workload. Repair the ring each time you decommission a node.
4. Update keyspaces with NetworkTopologyStrategy and replication factor to match the original RF

   ALTER KEYSPACE keyspace_name
   WITH REPLICATION =
     { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter_name' : 2 };
5. Change snitch on each node with restart.
6. Add nodes in a different datacenter. Make sure that when you add them you have auto_bootstrap: false in the cassandra.yaml
7. Run `nodetool rebuild original_dc_name` on each new node.

Comment: Thanks!! I still need some more clarification. What about the cassandra.toplogy.properties file for the existing nodes? do i need to create that file with restart?

Comment: Yes - when you change the snitch you will need to also create this file. And don't forget to set the node's own info in cassandra-rackdc.properties
I would recommend though to use gossipingPropertyFile snitch. This way you won't need to worry too much about the topology changes because the nodes will discover the topology via gossip and only if they can't they will resort to a property file

Comment: one more thing , i am not getting the meaning of "Decommission each node that is not a pure Cassandra workload". Could you please elaborate little bit?

Comment: If you're running datastax enterprise edition for example, then you may have analytics and search nodes. DSESimpleSnitch breaks the ring into DCs by the workload type. But you need to have only one DC in order to change the transition to NTS. Well maybe since you're using a simple snitch then this does not apply to you. I forgot to ask which edition - dse or community do you use?

Comment: am not using DSE. i am just using apache cassandra package

Comment: then you don't have that clause. you can just skip #3

Comment: okay. About the step1, what kind of repair should be done on all the nodes? and Why we need to do that since there was no change in the cluster?

Comment: You don't need to run the repairs if you do it on a regular basis. If you don't then (without going into the point of an importance of such repairs) it is always good to do so before significant changes, like this, because you should never assume that the transition will be smooth.

Answer (score -1):

I just found this excellent tutorial on migrating Cassandra:
[Cassandra Migration To EC2 by highscalability.com](http://highscalability.com/blog/2015/3/11/cassandra-migration-to-ec2.html)

Although the details will be found at the original article, an outline of the main steps are:

### 1. Cassandra Multi DC Support

1. Configure the PropertyFileSnitch
2. Update the replication strategy
3. Update the client connection setting

### 2. Setup Cassandra On EC2

4. Start the nodes
5. Stop the EC2 nodes and cleanup
6. Start the nodes
7. Place data replicas in the cluster on EC2

### 3. Decommission The Old DC And Cleanup

8. Decommission the seed node(s)
9. Update your client settings
10. Decommission the old data center